# I would like to select all views and for each view show all views dependent on that view

Tags: sql, database, dependencies, ssms

I'm trying to figure out which views in my database are no longer needed, so I'm making a document to track the dependencies of each view. There are hundreds of views in the database, so going through and checking the dependencies of each one-by-one would be time consuming. Is there a way to retrieve all the dependency information for each view? I am very new to SQL and SSMS.

Comment: Not needed? Used from procedures/other views, or from applications?

Answer (score 0):

Either of these two can display the dependencies

```
SELECT object_name(referenced_major_id)  
FROM sys.sql_dependencies
WHERE object_id = object_id('viewname')
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT referenced_entity_name 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('viewname', 'OBJECT')
```

For additional information, check this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/

Comment: This returned nothing when executed. Just to be clear: I would like a list of all dependencies for all views at once, not individually.

Comment: It does; I tried it. Replace 'viewname' with the name of the view you want to see dependencies on. For example, if the name of your view is 'vabc' replace viewname with 'vabc'

Comment: So this shows objects on which the view depends, but I would like objects that depend on the view. Also, I would like to execute this once and get a list for all my views rather than have to execute the query for each view.

Comment: Updated it with a link that may help you.

Comment: Okay that was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME() AS dbname, 
 o.type_desc AS referenced_object_type, 
 d1.referenced_entity_name, 
 d1.referenced_id, 
        STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + OBJECT_NAME(d2.referencing_id)
   FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d2
         WHERE d2.referenced_id = d1.referenced_id
                ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(d2.referencing_id)
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS dependent_objects_list
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  d1 JOIN sys.objects o 
  ON  d1.referenced_id = o.[object_id]
GROUP BY o.type_desc, d1.referenced_id, d1.referenced_entity_name
ORDER BY o.type_desc, d1.referenced_entity_name
```